# Assembly System.Windows.Forms - problems in Powershell command line

Tags: powershell, winforms

I have a simple GUI for calling REST APIs written in Powershell. Nothing too complicated - several text fields and buttons with built-in consistency checks. The script imports assembly System.Windows.Forms (`Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms`). The GUI works as expected when I run it from Powershell ISE.

However, when I run the same script from usual Powershell command line, the GUI doesn't work properly. The visual style looks completely different (Win95 style), popup message boxes don't appear throwing error messages instead ("not found"), Text property of some (but not all) elements can't be accessed / set (no reaction at all) and so on. The worst thing, it's impossible to debug such a script without ISE, and in ISE it works without a glitch.

Why this sudden difference in the behavior? Are there additional libraries loaded in the background by ISE? Or are there other factors?

Comment: Are you running the ISE in 64 bit and the PowerShell command line in 32 bit perhaps?

Comment: No, x86 versions are titled with that version in the window caption. Can't use them without noticing.

Comment: `X86` == 32 bit

Comment: All versions I use are x64

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. Don't forget ro provide error message(s) as well. Maybe missing `System.Drawing` or alike?